# Getting value from form without using onSubmit

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm wondering if there is an alternative way to run JavaScript when a button is submitted without using the onsubmit event. Thx

Comment: If your intention is to get the value and not to submit the form , then you can use the sumit listener and return before the form is submitted

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, give the button an ID, and utilize jQuery like this:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Code example from http://api.jquery.com/click/

You should use Google the next time more wisely. This is an easy one...